# Launch Firefox using a custom GTK theme

Tags: firefox, themes, xfce, default-browser

I found how to launch Firefox using this line of code with custom theme:

```
bash -c 'GTK_THEME="Arc-Darker-GalliumOS" firefox %u'
```

The thing is that when I open a link from an application it uses the default theme, which doesn't work well with Firefox.

So I opened up *Preferred Applications* and set as default web browser this line of code.

When I tested that, instead of opening the URL, it just went to `www.%u.com`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

- from bash (terminal emulator)

  ```
  GTK_THEME=Arc-Darker-GalliumOS firefox
  ```
- from a shortcut icon (`~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop`)

  ```
  Exec=env GTK_THEME=Arc-Darker-GalliumOS firefox %u
  ```